# how to store pdf file with file_get_contents - note - the pdf will be generated runtime based on url parameters

Tags: laravel, invoice

I'm using stripe to get invoice
I need to store this invoice in my public storage folder - I'm using laravel

stripe does not return pdf file path like this -  http://localhost/app/invoice.pdf

instead of that

they provide a url like this - https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/acct_1sflasjfmsklagbs/test_alkfnsajklgdbnajkgsbnajkfbsuayasgtjbwq8tuy23690q8319qr8busajvbssavkjsabngukwjqhr82rhadsawoilafkn/pdf?s=ap
so when you enter above url - it generates a pdf dynamically

I tried this and it works if you have direct path of pdf file

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://localhost/app/invoice.pdf');
    \Storage::disk('public')->put('filename.pdf', $contents);
```

but below given code does not work

```
$contents = file_get_contents('https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/acct_1sflasjfmsklagbs/test_alkfnsajklgdbnajkgsbnajkfbsuayasgtjbwq8tuy23690q8319qr8busajvbssavkjsabngukwjqhr82rhadsawoilafkn/pdf?s=ap');
    \Storage::disk('public')->put('filename.pdf', $contents);
```

anyone can please assist here?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices

Comment: @shailendra - it does not work - https://i.imgur.com/MoUl833.png - it will still return the same URL that I shared in task description

Comment: Ok then, can you create an invoice manually using Invoice object properties? you have to check which properties are useful for invoice.
and use any PDF library to create PDF from your side.